# How often to pass an object or variable through methods in Java?

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe, jpanel

I am new to stackoverflow and am sorry, if this question was already asked, but when I searched for one containing my problem, I could not find one.

Here is my question:

In Java I am creating a game (just for fun and am learning to code). You start my game with a launcher to log in. However, if you do not have an account, you can register. What I like more is to use one frame. I have a panel containing the launcher elements and one containing the register elements. I am trying to learn how to code, if another one is working on my project, he does not necessarily need to look all over the code to do some work. In other words, I am using packages to sort classes. Example: Classes for the launcher are in package Launcher. Classes for register are in package register.

In my code, I have a class called Display extending JFrame. Display is instanciated in the class with the main method. Display has 2 Methods for removing a panel and adding a panel, requiring you to pass a JPanel, if you use any of both methods. After Display is instantiated, it instantiates a jpanel inside the constructor. This has all the components to Display. The event listeners are in another class. So I am passing the buttons and Display to that class, because here is the eventlistener code for the button register. In my register class I have defined and instantiated all necessary components. I passed the display through all of the classes until it reached the register class which extends jpanel. I even passed the Launcher class. Now i can use the methods in display to remove the launcher panel and add my register panel.

**My Question:
is this good code or overkill?**

I never instantiated Display after the main method again. I always declared it and set it to the passed display. I did this, because instantiated a new Display would mean unnecessary use of memory and passing objects in java is actually a passing by references, meaning it is not passing the object but a pointer to the object. So this would mean less memory usage.

Comment: That is what I wrote in the last paragraph, still thank you.

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve what you seem to be trying. Personally, I'd avoid "exposing" the top level container, because other components shouldn't really care, they just need some support from it, like maybe access to the `glassPane` or `JMenuBar` or something, but those can be controlled through other managers, so they don't even need direct access to them. The point is to de-couple of the code, so if you wanted to display the components in `JInternalFrame`s instead, you'd not need to change the code of the components to do it

Comment: I would strongly recommend having a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  What you want is some kind of controller which knows how the navigation should work (because the login panel shouldn't care how the registration panel is implemented, it just needs to ask the controller to display it)